# Embed going outside of page width on Mobile - In Squarespace

Tags: html, squarespace

I'm looking for help on a very specific issue with the html/css on the mobile version of a page on our website on Squarespace. [See this page](https://www.blancaveils.com/design-your-own-custom-veil)

Specifically on mobile the embedded content is overflowing into and creating a white space to the right of the main content area. Ideally I would like it to simply display the entire embed within the bounds of the page on both full size, and mobile - but my limited coding knowledge has me up against a road-block.

Know the code is kind of all over the place, but any help or leads would be greatly appreciated!

```
.responsive-iframe-container {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 100%;
    padding-top: 60px;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.responsive-iframe-container iframe,   
.vresponsive-iframe-container object,  
.vresponsive-iframe-container embed {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```
<!--
<iframe onload="window.parent.scrollTo(0,0)" allowtransparency="true" allowfullscreen="true" allow="geolocation; microphone; camera" src="https://apps.blancaveils.com/veilMaker.html" frameborder="0" style="width: 850px; min-width: 100%; height:710px; border:none;" scrolling="no" > </iframe><script type="text/javascript"> var ifr = document.getElementById("JotFormIFrame-73548157882671"); if(window.location.href && window.location.href.indexOf("?") > -1) { var get = window.location.href.substr(window.location.href.indexOf("?") + 1); if(ifr && get.length > 0) { var src = ifr.src; src = src.indexOf("?") > -1 ? src + "&" + get : src + "?" + get; ifr.src = src; } } window.handleIFrameMessage = function(e) { var args = e.data.split(":"); if (args.length > 2) { iframe = document.getElementById("JotFormIFrame-" + args[(args.length - 1)]); } else { iframe = document.getElementById("JotFormIFrame"); } if (!iframe) { return; } switch (args[0]) { case "scrollIntoView": iframe.scrollIntoView(); break; case "setHeight": iframe.style.height = args[1] + "px"; break; case "collapseErrorPage": if (iframe.clientHeight > window.innerHeight) { iframe.style.height = window.innerHeight + "px"; } break; case "reloadPage": window.location.reload(); break; case "loadScript": var src = args[1]; if (args.length > 3) { src = args[1] + ':' + args[2]; } var script = document.createElement('script'); script.src = src; script.type = 'text/javascript'; document.body.appendChild(script); break; case "exitFullscreen": if (window.document.exitFullscreen) window.document.exitFullscreen(); else if (window.document.mozCancelFullScreen) window.document.mozCancelFullScreen(); else if (window.document.mozCancelFullscreen) window.document.mozCancelFullScreen(); else if (window.document.webkitExitFullscreen) window.document.webkitExitFullscreen(); else if (window.document.msExitFullscreen) window.document.msExitFullscreen(); break; } var isJotForm = (e.origin.indexOf("jotform") > -1) ? true : false; if(isJotForm && "contentWindow" in iframe && "postMessage" in iframe.contentWindow) { var urls = {"docurl":encodeURIComponent(document.URL),"referrer":encodeURIComponent(document.referrer)}; iframe.contentWindow.postMessage(JSON.stringify({"type":"urls","value":urls}), "*"); } }; if (window.addEventListener) { window.addEventListener("message", handleIFrameMessage, false); } else if (window.attachEvent) { window.attachEvent("onmessage", handleIFrameMessage); } </script>
-->


<div align="center"><iframe width="850" height="710" src="https://apps.blancaveils.com/veilMaker.html" frameborder="0"></iframe></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple things you'll need to do to accomplish that.

First, keep the iframe itself limited to a max-width of 100% the width of its container, like this:

```
iframe {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

Now, the next part requires that you have access to edit [the content that is within the iframe](https://apps.blancaveils.com/veilMaker.html), The `canvas` element within the iframe also needs to have its width similarly limited. However, you cannot add the following CSS via its parent (Squarespace). That is to say, adding the following CSS via the Squarespace CSS Editor will have no effect, because the nature of iframes requires the CSS to be defined within the iframe, not outside of it. So the following needs to be added **within veilMaker.html** not via Squarespace:

```
canvas {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

Keep in mind, however, that once you've achieved that, you may find that the user interface becomes too small to be usable on mobile. See here:

[image]

If it is the case that the UI is too small, you'll have to edit the `veilMaker.html` "app" itself to make it more responsive. That may require some rethinking of overall layout and design. For example, you may choose to reframe the canvas to crop out the empty space to the left, then perhaps shift the selectable options and navigation to the top or bottom of the canvas.